# Writing in a File when a button is clicked in a C++ GUI application

Tags: user-interface, file-handling, rad-studio

I am working on a C++ project that requires user registration and login. I am trying to build a GUI application using RAD studio in which the user will enter username and password for registration and when the 'Sign Up' button will be clicked, a file will be created in which the user's credentials will be stored. Later, when a user enters his credentials for login the program must check whether the username and password are correct or not by opening the file. If the credentials are the correct user will be successfully logged in.

I have done the same thing using file handling in C++ console but I am finding difficulty building the same program in GUI.

Error is shown in this code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    String input=Edit1->Text;
    ListBox1->Items->Add(input);


    string infile=Edit1->Text.c_str();

    ofstream g("registration.txt");

            g<<infile;
            g << '\n';
            g.close();
            Edit1->Text="";
}
```

Can someone please help me out or at least give me some hints on how to use file handing in GUI applications.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and paste the full error message verbatim. `Error is shown` is way too thin. Mention (tag) an implementation language!

Comment: (What is `infile`, and why doesn't `input` get used?)

Comment: `__fastcall` good grief. I don't *want* to be able to remember whether there was a reason to use something outside the language standard here. I'd have been happy to see a code comment motivating its use.